# Allow user to choose file/folder in C# WinForms app

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I user to choose a file or a folder from within my forms app?
Is there not a built in component for it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are a few depending on exactly what you need to do:

- [`OpenFileDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx)
- [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx)
- [`FolderBrowserDialog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.folderbrowserdialog.aspx)

Comment: The FolderBrowserDialog sucks, I'd expect something more like SaveFileDialog.... but I guess as long as it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CommonOpenFileDialog` by `WindowsAPICodePack` package to select a file and `dialog.IsFolderPicker = true` to enable folder selection